# Mongo Builder using `String` for `DateTime` class field

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a class with a field of type `DateTime`:

```
class Model {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

In the mongo database it is stored as:

`"Date" : "2018-02-01T13:22:08Z"`

Code:

```
var builder = Builders<Model>.Filter;

var filter = builder.In("Date", new[]
            {
               "2018-02-01T13:22:08Z"
            });

// Returns zero element list
_collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

The interesting thing is:

```
  var workingFilter = new BsonDocument()
        {
            { "Date", "2018-02-01T13:22:08Z"}
        };

// This one actually works
_collection.Find(workingFilter).ToList();
```

I think there is something wrong with Mongo's `Builder` utility when I provide a `string` as a value of `DateTime` field to get queried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your .NET `DateTime` is stored as a MongoDB `string` which is not a default behavior. By default you should be able to see something like this in your database:

```
"Date" : ISODate("2018-02-01T13:22:08Z")
```

So there is a mismatch between type stored in your database and type you have in your model. Keep in mind that MongoDB checks types before values and there's no implicit JavaScript-like casting.

In your working example you used `BsonDocument` which [handles dynamic documents](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/bson/bson_document/) so the driver simply ignored data type specified in your model and it gets translated to

```
db.yourCollection.find({"Date" : "2018-02-01T13:22:08Z"})
```

and returns that document.

Second code snippet uses generic `Filter` `Builder` so you specified that you care about types in `Model` class.

You can enable MongoDB profiler on level 2 and then run your .NET code:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

Then you can run following query on your database:

```
db.system.profile.find({ns: "yourdb.yourcollection"}).sort({ts:-1}).limit(1).pretty()
```

and you'll see the query that was generated by the driver:

```
"command" : {
            "find" : "yourcollection",
            "filter" : {
                    "Date" : {
                            "$in" : [
                                    ISODate("2018-02-01T13:22:08Z")
                            ]
                    }
            },
            "$db" : "yourdb"
    }
```

So as you can see the driver is aware of `DateTime` and converts your string to `ISODate` which causes type mismatch on database query level and that's why you are getting no results.

Solutions ? Either store your .NET `DateTime` as `ISODate` in MongoDB (recommended) or always use `BsonDocument` to build your queries.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `BsonDateTime` instead of a `DateTime` in your C#.  If you want to expose a .NET DateTime to your C# users and still persist the date as a date in Mongo, create two properties that get/set against the same backing store, and use some Mongo attributes to not persist the native DateTime and to rename the BsonDateTime.